# How do I pass an int array into an HTTP-triggered, dotnet-isolated V4 Azure Function as a body parameter?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, httprequest, azure-functions-isolated

I can make it work if I create a custom class that just serves as a wrapper for an integer array, but I'd rather not do that extra step. I want to just pass in an integer array.

This was my latest attempt:

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]
            HttpRequestData req)
        {
            var ids = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<int[]>(req.Body);
            ...
        }
```

I'm testing locally with Postman. I set the Body to JSON and my input looked like this:

```
{
    "ids": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

I'm getting a JSON serialization error, obviously, b/c it's expecting an object with just an array as it's only field, named "ids". But that's not how I want to solve this.

Previously, I was trying this (based on Mircosoft's own [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#payload)):

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using FromBodyAttribute = Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http.FromBodyAttribute;

public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]
            HttpRequestData req, [FromBody] int[] ids)
        {
             ....
        }
```

When I use the JSON Body input approach above via Postman, I get the same serialization error.

When I try just passing it in as raw text like `[1, 2, 3]` I get a System.InvalidOperationException with the message: `'System.Int32[]' is not supported by the 'DefaultFromBodyConversionFeature'`

Obviously based on that last exception, it seems like `[FromBody]` isn't the way to go. But there has to be some way to do this that I'm missing. This seems like a trivial problem and I'm frustrated that I haven't found a solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content of your body is simply:

```
[1,2,3]
```

You can deserialize it using:

```
public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestData req)
{
   var ids = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<int>>(req.Body);
   ...
}
```

Otherwise, if you're input is:

```
{
   "ids": [1,2,3]
}
```

Then you can't deserialize the contents without a class definition like:

```
public class IdsDto
{
   public List<int> ids { get; set; }
}
```

That you could then use like this:

```
var idsDto = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IdsDto>(req.Body);
var ids = idsDto.ids;
```

If you **really** want to avoid the intermediate class, you could perform some dirty string manipulation to leave yourself with only the `int[]`:

```
var intArrayString = req.Body.substring(req.Body.IndexOf('['), req.Body.IndexOf(']') - req.Body.IndexOf('[') + 1);
// And then:
var intArray = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<int>>(intArrayString);
```

But, honestly, I would go with the intermediate class.

Comment: Your initial solution is exactly what I was looking for. If I end up needing to pass in more data, I'll certainly go with the intermediate class, but right now it's just a list of ids, so the intermediate class seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for deserializing JSON expects to receive int array in the request body. However, you are passing an object when calling from Postman. Try sending the following payload in Postman:

```
[
    1,
    2,
    3
]
```

Then your Azure Function can deserialize the request body:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseData> RunAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]
            HttpRequestData req, [FromBody] int[] ids)
{
    var ids = req.ReadFromJsonAsync<int[]>();      
}
```